# How to optimized mysql query having large dataset

Tags: mysql, database, query-performance

I have two tables with the following schema,

```
CREATE TABLE `open_log` (
  `delivery_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_activity` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `click_url` text,
  `email_code` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `on_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `sent_log` (
  `email_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tries` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_ts` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_dt` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `on_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The email_id and delivery_id columns in both tables make up a unique key.

The open_log table have 2.5 million records where as sent_log table has 0.25 million records.

I want to filter out the records from open log table based on the unique key (email_id and delivery_id).

I'm writing the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM open_log
WHERE CONCAT(email_id,'^',delivery_id) 
IN (
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(email_id,'^',delivery_id) FROM sent_log
)
```

The problem is the query is taking too much time to execute. I've waited for an hour for the query completion but didn't succeed.

Kindly, suggest what I can do to make it fast since, I have the big data size in the tables.

Thanks,
Faisal Nasir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, rewrite your query using `exists`:

```
SELECT *
FROM open_log ol
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM send_log sl
              WHERE sl.email_id = ol.email_id and sl.delivery_id = ol.delivery_id
             );
```

Then, add an index so this query will run faster:

```
create index idx_sendlog_emailid_deliveryid on send_log(email_id, delivery_id);
```

Your query is slow for a variety of reasons:

- The use of string concatenation makes it impossible for MySQL to use an index.
- The `select distinct` in the subquery is unnecessary.
- `Exists` can be faster than `in`.

Comment: which index it will create clustered or non-clustered ?

Comment: The index would be unclustered.  I wouldn't recommend a clustered index on `emailid` -- the clustering would guarantee the ordering which would make inserts expensive.

Answer (score 0):

If this request is often on, you can greatly increase it by create bigint id column, enven if it not unique.

For example you can put trigger and create column  like this

```
alter table sent_log for_get bigint;
```

After that create trigger/ update it to put hash into that bigint

```
for_get=CONV(substr(md5(concat(email_id, delivery_id)),1,10),16,10)
```

If you have such column in both table and index on it, query will be like

```
SELECT *
FROM open_log ol
left join send_log sl on sl.for_get=ol.for_get
      WHERE sl.email_id is not null and sl.email_id = ol.email_id and sl.delivery_id = ol.delivery_id;
```

That query will be fast.

Comment: if I convert the same email_id and delivery_id value again then it will give me the same result... right ?

Comment: Yes, that is simple hash function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function . Can be 2+ equal values map  different info, but that is not so often situation and will be removed by WHERE cause. Index for bigint is much smaller if compare with 2 varchar, so it will be fast.